# Can't connect sparklyr to shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, dbi, sparklyr

I'm pretty new to Shiny and Spark.

I want to deploy a ShinyApp with a spark connection.  Everything works how it should when I just hit RunApp, but whenever I try to publish it, I get the error: "Error in value[3L] : 
  SPARK_HOME directory '/usr/lib/spark' not found
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
Execution halted"

This directory exists on my cluster, so I'm not sure why it's not finding it.
Here's the code I'm trying to publish.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rmarkdown)


Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = '/usr/lib/spark')
config<- spark_config()
spark_install(version = "2.2.0")
sc<-spark_connect(master = 'yarn-client',  version = '2.2.0')
tbl_cache(sc, 'output_final_v2')
output_tbl2<-tbl(sc, 'output_final_v2') 


ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput("name", "Enter Name", "company"),
  textInput("item_name", "Enter Item Name"),
  selectInput("month", "Choose Month", choice= 
 c("January","February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December")),

selectInput("dow","Choose Day of Week", choice = c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")),
  numericInput("count_customers", "Enter Number of Customers:", 2),
  numericInput("views", "Enter Number of Views:", 30),


  plotOutput("plot1"),
  plotOutput("plot2"),
  plotOutput("plot3")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  C2<-reactive( output_tbl2 %>%
              mutate(views = input$views)%>%
              filter(input$name == shortname)%>%
              filter(input$dow== dow)%>%
              filter (input$month == month)%>%
              filter (input$item_name == item)%>%
              filter (input$count_customers == count_customers)%>%
              collect)
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

p1<-ggplot2::ggplot(data = C2() , aes(x=price_per_customer, y=final_probability)) + geom_line() + ggtitle("Probability of Purchase") + labs(y="Probability",x= "Item Price")
print(p1)
  })


  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

p2<-ggplot2::ggplot(data=C2(), aes(x=price_per_customer, y=((views*final_probability)*price_per_customer))) + geom_line() + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = max((views*final_probability)*price_per_customer))) + ggtitle("Projected Revenue") + labs(y="Expected Revenue",x="Item Price")  
print(p2)

  })

  output$plot3<-renderPlot({

p3<-ggplot2::ggplot(data=C2(), aes(x=price_per_customer))+ geom_line(aes(y=(views*final_probability)*price_per_customer)) + geom_line(aes(y= (((views*final_probability)/price_per_customer)))) + ggtitle("Iso-Profit vs Expected Volume")

print(p3)  
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Where are you trying to publish the app to? Also, I'm guessing the first 10 lines of your script would suffice as a minimal example reproducing the problem...

Comment: I'm trying to publish it to shiny-server. You're correct about reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this same issue, here's the answer that fixed it for me: https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1100#issuecomment-342313877